# Eclipse Mars “<” icon for directory is really annoying

Tags: eclipse

Like this:

[image: like this]

The bigger < is really annoying, because it looks much like the small one, how can I hide it?

Comment: You can't control the first `>` arrow as it is from underlying OS. You can change the themes(on Linux) so it will look differently. So on Linux mint/Ubuntu/KDE this collapse tree node icon(`>`) looks different.

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean the same thing:

- the `>` on the left allows you to open the directory.
- the `>` on the right is an EGit marker that shows that the directory is *dirty*: it has files in it with pending changes.

If you want to, you can change the EGit marker to something else, or disable it entirely, using the Preferences dialog under Team -> Git -> Label Decorations -> Text Decorations.